# Change java method inner variables value from other methods in the same class

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

#### Here's a Interview question.

Question:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int a= 10;
        int b=10;
        method(a,b);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static void method(int a,int b){
        //**Under the premise of not changing the original question, how to write this function in the main function to output a=100，b=200？**
    
    }
}
```

Answers:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field; 

class Text
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 10;
    method(a,b);
    System.out.println("a = " + a);
    System.out.println("b = " + b);
  }
  private static void method(Integer a, Integer b) throws Exception
  {
    Field fielda = a.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
    fielda.setAccessible(true);
    fielda.set(a,100);
    System.out.println("a = " + a); 
    Field fieldb = b.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
    fieldb.setAccessible(true);
    fieldb.set(b,200);
    System.out.println("b = " + b); 
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

And we can overwrite function print. in function 'method. etc...

#### So, my questions are:

1. Why `a.getClass().getDeclaredField("value")` can get variabe "a" from method main? I checked each item  of `a.getClass().getDeclaredFields` returned array in debug mode, but did not find any regularities.
   Are there any refers  about every item meaning  of `a.getClass().getDeclaredFields` returned array.
2. I know that methods' inner variables save in stack memory,and shared in the same thread. Can we change variable main's "a" value through Reflection or Using a new Java classloader?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your question 1.  But the answer to your question 2 is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a big disguise. It doesn’t change the variables of the `main` method at all. Note that it also changed the question’s method declaration from `void method(int a,int b)` to `void method(Integer a, Integer b)` (I’m not sure whether this is allowed for solutions), to enforce a boxing conversion from `int` to `Integer`. (It also added `throws Exception` declarations that weren’t in the original code).

Therefore, the `a.getClass().getDeclaredField("value")` expression doesn’t access anything from the `main` method, but the `value` field of the wrapper class `java.lang.Integer`. Then, access override is used to modify the `value` field.

But note that this nasty hack still has no effect on the `main` method. Since the main method uses `int` primitives, these values are unaffected by any manipulation of the `java.lang.Integer` instances. That’s why the solution uses another trick—it does the printing itself using the lines

```
System.out.println("a = " + a);
```

and

```
System.out.println("b = " + b);
```

followed by

```
System.exit(0);
```

Since *these* print statements are using the `Integer` objects, they are affected by the hack, whereas the `System.exit(0)` call ensures that the method never returns to the `main` method, so the `main` method’s print statements are never executed.

Once you understand the “do the printing yourself and exit the JVM” part, you recognize that the entire Reflection hack is entirely unnecessary. You can achieve exactly the same using

```
public static void method(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("a = 100");
    System.out.println("b = 200");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This does exactly the same as the solution and it doesn’t even need to change the question’s method signature. But, of course, without the distracting Reflection hack, it’s more obvious what’s actually going on.

---

That said, Reflection doesn’t offer any way to access local variables. You would need a debugger for that. Since you also asked for a `ClassLoader`, you can manipulate the code of a class to use different values, but that wouldn’t fulfill the question’s requirement of doing it inside of `method`, i.e. while the code in question is already running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
There exactly exist so many tricks in this interview question.But it also challenges our knowledge about JVM. 
About  a.getClass().getDeclaredField("value") ,where does the param “value” from . It represents  a default input param of "method" ?  U said it  only changes the value field of the wrapper class java.lang.Integer. Are there any wiki pages or books I can refer to about it ?

Comment: I doubt that there is a book regarding such tricks. In this specific case, it’s not really hard, you only have to look *carefully*. In the interview answer, `a` is a parameter of the method, declared to be `Integer`. So `a.getClass()` is nothing special, it returns the `Class` of the `Integer` instance. You can see the presence of the `value` field [in the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Integer.java#834). Note that the source code is also shipped with the jdk, debuggers with GUI are capable of browsing or stepping into it.